# How to return Boolean value if values exists in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display an boolean value for the audit trail of a oracle database.

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from 
   (Select VALUE FROM v$parameter WHERE UPPER (name) = 'AUDIT_TRAIL') 
   where value in('OS','DB')  ) 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0  
   END 
FROM dual ;
```

Is there a way to display a boolean instead of 1 or 0. The values can be OS or DB.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  I don't understand how a "boolean" value can have values of OS or DB.

Comment: Oracle SQL does not support the Boolean data type. But even if it did, what do you mean by "display a Boolean"? Boolean values are not displayable; we use 0 and 1, or 'Y' and 'N', or 'true' and 'false' - the **displaying** is always as number or as string, even if the language did support the Boolean type. Do you mean you want to display 'true' and/or 'false'? You can do that directly in your query - just replace 1 and 0 with the strings 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: Your condition is too complicated, too:  `case when exists (select * from v$parameter where upper(name) = 'AUDIT_TRAIL' and value in ('OS', 'DB')) then 'true' else 'false' end` does the same job.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle sql do not have boolean data type.

You can use the following query to directly return 0 or 1 and use them as boolean:

```
Select case when count(1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as result
FROM v$parameter WHERE UPPER (name) = 'AUDIT_TRAIL' and value in('OS','DB')
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `case when count(1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as result` by simply `(count(1) > 0) as result`? How does Oracle output that boolean value?

Comment: Why would you `COUNT` (an additional calculation) when you only need to test for existence? An `EXISTS` condition will exit successfully as soon as the first matching row is found; `COUNT` will force the execution engine to continue execution until all the matching rows are counted. I am not a big fan of this approach, for the reason I just gave.